# How to check if a string contains hashtags in dart?

Tags: string, if-statement, flutter, dart, hashtag

guys,

I am developing a social media app and I want people to see hashtags and for that, I want to check if a string contains any hashtags like : #I_am_nice.

Notice that I want to get all the hashtag not only the first word after hashtag mark(#).

My wants :

```dart
if (string.contains(Hashtag)) {
  print(hashtag);//Hashtag String
 } else {
  //No Hashtags
 }
```

thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This Dart code will do what you are looking for:

```
String text = "Test #first1hashtag test #second2hashtag test.";
RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"\B#\w\w+");
exp.allMatches(text).forEach((match){
  print(match.group(0));
});
```

Result:

> #first1hashtag
>
> #second2hashtag

Comment: I'm using your code right now for a personal app. I was wondering if the tag is located at the end of a string how would you go about removing it? I asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74151928/strip-any-hashtags-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-dart. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Updated your regex to support words with dashes `r"\B#[\w-]+"`.