# Strip any hashtags at the end of a string in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently extracting hashtags from a string and adding them to an array but how can I remove them from the string as well *provided* they are located by the end?

For example:

```dart
// Random string with tags
String message = "Hello #tag1 and #tag2 the end #tag3 #tag4";
RegExp regex = RegExp(r"\B#\w\w+");
List<String> tags = [];

// Add each tag to list
regex.allMatches(message).forEach((match){
  tags.add(match.group(0)!);
});
```

How to remove `#tag3 #tag4` from the original string so it's updated to look:

```dart
Hello #tag1 and #tag2 the end
```

The only reason I'm keeping `#tag1` and `#tag2` is because it would look weird if they were taken out since it's within a sentence. Note that the string can be anything.

Original code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454111/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-hashtags-in-dart).

Comment: if ``the end`` is constant in the string then why don't just split the string using ``the end`` as separator ?

Comment: It's just a sample string. The string could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String text = "Test #tag1 and #tag2 end #tag3 #tag4";
String resultText = "";
var l = text.split(" ");
int index = l.lastIndexWhere((element) => !element.contains('#'));
l.removeRange(index + 1, l.length);
resultText = l.join(' ');
print("resultText= $resultText"); //resultText= Test #tag1 and #tag2 end
```

Comment: I modified the solution to use `resultText = l.join(' ');`

Comment: @enchance yeah that is great. I updated my answer with that.